# Camunda 403 error when rest-api request sent from ui

Tags: rest, authentication, axios, bpmn, camunda

I'm trying out Camunda with authentication filter. The same request works fine with basic auth from postman, but when i send it from the UI I get 403 error for the OPTIONS request and the POST request fails.
PS: I have my cors filter set up, it works fine if I disable the authentication filter.
This is the request in postman
[image]

and this is the request in my code

```js
await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/process-definition/key/${process.env.REACT_APP_PROCESS}/start`, {}, {
            headers: { 'Authorization': 
                {username: "demo",
                password: "demo"}
            }
        })
```

I tried also this syntax:

```js
await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/process-definition/key/${process.env.REACT_APP_PROCESS}/start`, {}, {
            auth: 
                {username: "demo",
                password: "demo"}
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned in [this](https://forum.camunda.org/t/get-rest-request-with-authorization-yields-403-in-preflight/6475) post its a problem with
**cors.allowed.headers** in the **web.xml** file. I added **Authorization** in the filter and no more 403 error:

```xml
<init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization</param-value>
</init-param>
```